# Can turtles move the lateral direction (left or right) in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

My simulated turtles can move forward and backward.

In addition to it, I want to move turtles towards left or right directions with their heading direction keeping.

However, I don't know how codes acheves it.

Please tell me any codes to program it in NetLogo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a turtle move left one square, have it do:

```
lt 90
fd 1
rt 90
```